# Creating and manipulating EF1 data model in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a project which requires me to work with .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and not 4.

My primary tool is Visual Studio 2010. I want to use Entity Framework as my data layer (since there's a nice and quick designer to work with in Visual Studio; other ORMs don't have this privilege so you have to do it pretty much manually - code or XML or similar) but since EF4 only works with .Net 4 I obviously have to use EF1 (I'd use EF Extensions with it as well).

But is it at all possible to create EF1 data model in Visual Studio 2010? There's just ADO.NET Entity Data Model project item and I'm pretty confident this one's related to EF4.

My project is set to use .Net Framework 3.5 (no way to select SP1 in project settings but this is not really relevant). Does this setting also set EF model to be EF1 instead of EF4 when I'd create it?

Comment: why would you want to use EF1? even microsoft say that its not very good in comparison to Linq2SQL - do you have to use it?

Comment: @PaulStack: No I don't, but I used it several times (even on complex things and even with MySql) and I liked it very much. When you use it for some time, you know the quirks and know how to avoid problematic situations. Add to that EF Extensions and you're in a win-all situation. That's why I'd rather use EF1 over any other OR/M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch target.NET Framework to version 3.5 it should offer you only parts related to .NET 3.5 (SP1).

Comment: Are you sure, because when I changed from 3.5 to 4 I still had just one project item called **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** and none that would relate to EF4. Because it would of course be possible to have them both available when working on .net 4 wouldn't it?